# Adding a New Entity via Data Binding on a Details Form.

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, data-binding

How can I use data binding on a details form to add a new entity to my data source? I have created an Object data source, and dragged it onto my form as 'details', which automatically adds a bindingSource and bindingNavigator control to my form, in addition to data bound detail fields. I have the following code which all executes with no exceptions, but no new Branch record gets added when I click 'Add New' and then 'Save'.

```
private void BranchEditForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    branchBindingSource.DataSource = _loansEntities.Branches;
}

private void branchBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _loansEntities.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
}
```

I can't seem to find any Entity Framework data binding examples that don't just default to grids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a new record generated through a details form can be done by calling the the relevant add method in the model before calling the `SaveChanges` method to commit the record to data source.

For the above, this code might solve the problem, presuming there is a method called `AddToBranches` which takes a `Branch` object as an argument.

```
_loanEntities.AddToBranches((Branch)branchBindingSource.Current));
_loansEntities.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.AcceptAllChangesAfterSave);
```